# Active Storage upload images even when the form has errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Yestarday when I was doing some tests on a vehicle form, I didn't filled any fields other than my file upload. I put in there some images and then I hit the submit button. Because some attributes have validations the form come back with errors (as intended) but the images were already uploaded. Now if I decide to exit the form, I will not insert any vehicle but I already inserted images. That images are not purge when I exit my form.

Question: The upload should not only insert them after verifying if there is no errors in the form? And if this is the normal procedure then what I have to do to fix this?

The only thing that comes in my mind is doing something like this (and I think this is not a smart think to do):

```
#vehicles_controller.rb

def create
  @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)
  if @vehicle.save
    redirect_to @vehicle
  else
    @vehicle.images.purge <--------
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This works fine if I don't use the [direct upload](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) of Active Storage, where in this case this error appears:

[image]

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When using Direct Upload the files are uploaded to storage as soon as they are attached to the form, not when the form is submitted.

What happens is when the files are attached, the browser makes a request to Rails for a temporary direct upload URL to your storage (S3, Azure, Google, etc), hence the name Direct Upload. This means that the files do not have to be streamed through your server, which takes a lot of unnecessary strain off it. When Rails is responding with the temporary upload URL, it also creates a Blob record and sends a key for that blob to the browser also.

Once the browser has successfully processed the Direct Upload, it will hide a hidden element in the DOM which references the blob key. Then when you submit the form, if the submit action succeeds, Rails will attach the Blob to your Vehicle model (using a polymorphic ActiveStorage::Attachment record). Only at this point is the image (Blob) actually attached to your Vehicle record.

If the form submission fails, then the Blob does not get attached to your record. If this happens you cannot purge the Blob using the method described above since it is not associated with the `@vehicle`. A sensible solution might be to run a rake task periodically that searches for Blobs that have no attachments, and purges them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I was using the direct upload for the feedback I receive when uploading images with big size. Because in reality my app is hosted in DigitalOcean and I'm not using any cloud service as S3, Azure, etc (I think so..). Can I ask if its better to not use direct upload and purge all the images if the form submission fails? Thanks again :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, if you're not using Direct Upload then the Blob will not be created before the form submission so you will not have this issue and will not need to purge if the form submission fails as the Blob won't have been created.